# Will UUID be the same if a disk moved from one machine to another?

Tags: linux, uuid

While in Linux every disk got a UUID.
I just wondering will the UUID be the same if I moved the same disk from one Linux box to another?

Is it the same UUID in different machines with the same disk?
Or for a disk the UUID will change with attached machine?

Also a similar question:
Will the UUID be the same after Linux distribution reinstalled in the same machine with the same disk?
For example: First is CentOS 5, then reinstalled it to CentOS 6.

Comment: Do you really mean disk? Or do you mean partition/filesystem?

Comment: Do you mean slices/partitions? Partition UUID's will be the same across different machines (they are stored in the MBR/GPT) but the UUID changes on each format. (So going from CentOS 5 to CentOS 6 with a format would result in a new UUID.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Every filesystem has a UUID, which is stored as part of the partition table on the disk itself, so is "portable" with the disk.

Upgrading your OS should only change the UUID of a partition if that partition was formatted.